# Java, map a json

Tags: java, json

Here's what I wanna do
I have a json, like:

```
{
  "demoNumber":123,
  "demoText":"asdasdasd"
}
```

and I wanna make a simple String array from it, which should be

```
["demoNumber","demoText"]
```

In the app we're making the user can add any type of data, so we can't do data models for everything, that's not an option

I have added json to my Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20180130'
}
```

But it still can't find the method.

Comment: So what did you try..?

Comment: Something like Paul answered, I just can't find that map method

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the JSON as a string, this example uses the [JSON-java library](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java):

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(myJsonStr);
Set<String> keys = jo.toMap().keySet();
// You should be able to extract an array from the set of keys
```

See also https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json

Comment: Maybe i ducked up something but I get cannot resolve method toMap

Comment: update, added org.json to gradle, and it still cant find this method

Comment: That's odd because the method is in the source code (last method in class): https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java  We use the library in our project and I can confirm the method is there. Be sure you're using version 20180813 or 20180130, I know for sure the method is in both of those versions.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the code and found the method too, but android studio somewhy cannot find it. The only thing I have to do is import it in my gradle right?

Comment: Yes.  Check the version you're using by running `gradle -q dependencies --configuration compile`.  You can leave off `--configuration compile` to see the dependencies for all configurations.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html

Comment: Is there an API level limit for this? That's the only thing I haven't tried yet

Comment: I don't understand your question. We declare the dependency in Gradle like so: `compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'`. I know version 20160212 does not have `JSONObject.toMap()` because the 20160212 API is posted here: http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html  Use the latest version of the library and you'll have what you need.

Comment: yes, exactly. I wrote exactly this. And still... "error: cannot find symbol method toMap()"